# does a after_created Rails callback method on a model have an instance of the newly created model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback

I have a after_create method for my Contact model.

However, when I put the value, it comes out nil.  How can I have a callback for a newly created model ( I do a fair amount of transformation in the create model) referenced within the callback method?

```
after_save   :update_company 

 def update_company   

   puts self.inspect
   puts self.company

   if company.phone.empty? 

      company.phone = self.phone
      company.save

   end       

 end
```

When I look at the logs for self.inspect, it doesn't show any of the transformations used in the create method...yet, this should run only after it has created (and saved), the object, right?

Here is the create method:

```
  def create

    @contact = Contact.create(params[:contact])

     unless @contact.vcard.path.blank?

           paperclip_vcard = File.new(@contact.vcard.path) 

       @vcard = Vpim::Vcard.decode(paperclip_vcard).first
       @contact.title = @vcard.title
       @contact.email = @vcard.email
       @contact.first_name = @vcard.name.given
       @contact.last_name = @vcard.name.family
       @contact.phone = @vcard.telephone
       @contact.address.street1 = @vcard.address.street
       @contact.address.city = @vcard.address.locality
       @contact.address.state = @vcard.address.region
       @contact.address.zip = @vcard.address.postalcode
       @contact.company_name = @vcard.org.fetch(0)

    end

    @contact.user_id = current_user.id # makes sure every new user is assigned an ID    
    if @contact.save
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully created contact."
      redirect_to @contact
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end
```

Comment: `if company.phone.blank?` try that

Comment: I put a whole bunch of stuff in the create method....does after-create mean it will do it after it goes through the create method...because it doesn't appear to be doing so....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this happens because you didn't use self when assigning the value to company object.

In ruby, generally you don't require the use have "self" to retrieve attributes of an instance

for example in your code. you can  `puts company`  and it would work fine.

but when assigning (on the left hand side )  you always have to use self.

so change this in  your code.

```
  self.company.phone = self.phone
  company.save
```

or

```
 
  self.company.phone = phone 
  company.save
```

Comment: actually I found that if the controller has a create, it uses that as a save, so it was happening too soon...